# How to do a get request twice in PHP?

Tags: php, json, api, drupal, request

Here's my current code:

```
$header = [ 
                'phoneType' => $mobileType
                ];

\Drupal::logger("cam")->debug('PageNameHere retrieveAPINameHere REQUEST: '.json_encode($header));
            $filterPhone = MAPClient2::req( 'get', $context, $header, NULL);
```

Now, I need to make two request now with a new API with the following request:

```
{
"configuration": "techDescriptions",
"automated":"<phon>",
"lalaBox":true
}

{
"configuration": "techDescriptions",
"automationBu":"<phoneType>",
"lalaBox":false
 }
```

Is this the right way to do it?

```
$header = [ 
                "configuration": "techDescriptions",
                "automationBu":"<phoneType>",
                "lalaBox":false
                ];

$header = [ 
                "configuration": "techDescriptions",
                "automationBu":"<phoneType>",
                "lalaBox":treu
                ];

\Drupal::logger("cam")->debug('PageNameHere retrieveNEWAPINameHere REQUEST: '.json_encode($header));
            $filterPhone = MAPClient2::req( 'get', $context, $header, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing this you overwrite the $header variable. You should maybe have another name that makes more sense for the second header you need to send. I'll put $header2 so you understand but you should find a better name

```
       $header = [ 
                        "configuration": "techDescriptions",
                        "automationBu":"<phoneType>",
                        "lalaBox":false
                        ];

        $header2 = [ 
                        "configuration": "techDescriptions",
                        "automationBu":"<phoneType>",
                        "lalaBox":treu
                        ];

\Drupal::logger("cam")->debug('PageNameHere retrieveNEWAPINameHere REQUEST: '.json_encode($header));
            $filterPhone = MAPClient2::req( 'get', $context, $header, NULL);

\Drupal::logger("cam")->debug('PageNameHere retrieveNEWAPINameHere REQUEST: '.json_encode($header));
            $filterPhone = MAPClient2::req( 'get', $context, $header2, NULL);
```

Comment: wondering how i'll do the response with two requests now? i have this: 
\Drupal::logger("cam")->debug('PageNameHere retrieveNEWAPINameHere RESPONSE: '.json_encode($filterPhone)); do i make two response as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
$header = [ 
                "configuration": "techDescriptions",
                "automationBu":"<phoneType>",
                "lalaBox":false
                ];

\Drupal::logger("cam")->debug('PageNameHere retrieveNEWAPINameHere REQUEST: '.json_encode($header));
            $filterPhone1 = MAPClient2::req( 'get', $context, $header, NULL);
$header = [ 
                "configuration": "techDescriptions",
                "automationBu":"<phoneType>",
                "lalaBox":treu
                ];

\Drupal::logger("cam")->debug('PageNameHere retrieveNEWAPINameHere REQUEST: '.json_encode($header));
        $filterPhone2 = MAPClient2::req( 'get', $context, $header, NULL);
```

Just do 2 requests. In your example, you only overwrite the header variable. And I think the in the second header you mean true not treu?

Comment: wondering how i'll do the response with two requests now? i have this: 
\Drupal::logger("cam")->debug('PageNameHere retrieveNEWAPINameHere RESPONSE: '.json_encode($filterPhone)); do i make two response as well?

Comment: Yea you can also make 2 responses.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could also put the 2 headers together in one array and later call them twice as :

```
\Drupal::logger("cam")->debug('PageNameHere retrieveNEWAPINameHere REQUEST: '.json_encode($header));
        $filterPhone = MAPClient2::req( 'get', $context, $header[0], NULL);

\Drupal::logger("cam")->debug('PageNameHere retrieveNEWAPINameHere REQUEST: '.json_encode($header));
        $filterPhone = MAPClient2::req( 'get', $context, $header[1], NULL);
```

But you don't win much though, but might be more convenient later when you want to add more headers.

Comment: wondering how i'll do the response with two requests now? i have this: 
\Drupal::logger("cam")->debug('PageNameHere retrieveNEWAPINameHere RESPONSE: '.json_encode($filterPhone)); do i make two response as well?  @Wkoppel

Comment: Well as you are sending two different parameters for this then you are excepting two different outcomes. You could have it in one variable though. Create a function which will proccess the $filterPhone, call it after your first call, and after your second call you can do the same with same variable name as you are reassigning its value with response from the call. But I am not quite familiar what you exactly trying to do. Good luck!